# malloc and free in loops. object was probably modified after being freed.?

Tags: c, memory, malloc, free, allocation

I have created a multilevel cache simulator, and to find the best performance cache, I have made loops that loop for quite a while.

Since each loop is allocating memory, with malloc, I freed up whatever it malloced, but I get this error when I run:

> "incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed"

Here's part of the code

Here's where it allocates memory:

```
/* cache1 */
if (S1 == 0) {
    L1 = 1;
    d_Cache1.cache_Array = (aBlock *)malloc((int)pow(2, (C1-B1)) * sizeof(aBlock));
    /* static int cache1[(int)pow(2,(C1 - B1))]; */
} else if (S1 == C1-B1) {
    L1 = 2;
    f_Cache1.cache_Array = (aBlock *)malloc((int)pow(2, (C1-B1)) * sizeof(aBlock));
} else {
    L1 = 3;
    s_Cache1.cache_Array = malloc((int)pow(2, (C1 - S1 - B1))*sizeof(aBlock *));
    if(s_Cache1.cache_Array == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
        return;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < (int)pow(2, (C1 - S1 - B1)); i++) {
        s_Cache1.cache_Array[i] = malloc((int)pow(2, S1) * sizeof(aBlock));
        if (s_Cache1.cache_Array[i] == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
            return;
        }
    }

    sc_Count1 = malloc((int)pow(2,S1) * sizeof(aBlock));
    for (i = 0; i < (int)pow(2, S1); i++) {
        sc_Count1[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

and after performing everything, it frees up:

```
//cache1
if (S1 == 0) {
    free(d_Cache1.cache_Array);
} else if (S1 == C1-B1) {
    free(f_Cache1.cache_Array);
} else {
    for (i = 0;  i < (int)pow(2, (C1 - S1 - B1)); i++) {
        free(s_Cache1.cache_Array[i]);
    }

    free(s_Cache1.cache_Array);
    free(sc_Count1);
}
```

What could be causing this memory issue?
I'm freeing up the exact memory that i allocate, and value of `S1`, `C1`, `B1` never changes until next loop.

Comment: Could you possibly tidy up the formating.

Comment: If you're on linux, use Valgrind to find this and stop burning braincells :)

Answer (score 1):

Quite possibly the problem is in the middle - at least, I don't see where you do anything with the memory you malloc. Are you just zeroing out the array, or do you do something else with it? `incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed` often comes from smashing the memory contents around the memory you malloc'd (that is, index out of bounds) or doing exactly what it's telling you - modifying the memory contents after freeing them - and that's my best guess as to what's happening.

As a measure of protection, when in debug mode, some compilers will put in a checksum around the memory to see if it gets modified after being freed, and if you do modify it, it won't match the checksum. The compiler is telling you you're messing with the contents of a chunk of memory that you have freed. Often times, the extra cost of check only happens when mallocing or freeing, so that's why it seems to be associated with those calls.

You may be tracking your malloc and frees just fine, but the next thing I would look at is the state of the memory when you write into it.

Answer (score 0):

first

> s_Cache1.cache_Array=malloc(...

then

> s_Cache1.cache_Array[i]=malloc(..

Looks a bit suspicious in my eyes. malloc something within something already malloced?

Comment: That's actually pretty common. `malloc` an array of pointers, then `malloc` each element.

Comment: Thanks, I was going to ask if it was something you could do.